# Maximo - Automation Script. how to use yncerror

Tags: maximo

I have a button. on click, I am calling an automation script. I need to pop up a confirm dialog box. I am doing this using service.yncerror() and its working fine.

But I need to pop-up one more message box/dialog box for user confirmation. How will I handle this new dialog box ?

Comment: You need to have a confirmation box pop up from a confirmation box? Interesting. In theory, it would be the same as the first ync box. It going to call the configured methods in the same script. You _could_ reuse the same methods, or have a second set of methods that gets called instead (which is probably better from the view of making the code more understandable).